# El fragment no abre completo en la pantalla

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Mi problema radica en lo siguiente, tengo 3 listview en un fragment, lo cual me corre bastante bien, la cuestión esta en que cuando lleno los `ListView` respectivamente, se nota que carga todo pero no se ve en mi pantalla, se hace un miniScroll en el último `ListView`, no quiero que sea así, quisiera que el scroll sea general y que los `ListView` tengan el tamaño y ya. Adiciono el código de las actividades relacionadas y una vista.

**MenuCetral.java** (es un simple navigation drawer donde en la seccion de "inicio" debe reflejar el fragment con los listview)

```
  public class MenuCentral extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_central);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_central, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ProfesoresF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new CalendarioF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new AjustesF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PerfilF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

**InicioF.java** (fragmento que me esta sacando canas verdes, en el esta los 3 listview)

```
 public class InicioF extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

    String[] menuDias = {   "Tare",
                            "Trabajo",
                            "Salida"};

    String[] menu15Das = {  "Tare",
                            "Trabajo",
                            "Salida"};

    String[] menumes = {    "Tare",
                            "Trabajo",
                            "Salida"};



    //adaptadores
    //adaptador dias
    ListView listdias = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.menudias);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listavistadias = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuDias);


    listdias.setAdapter(listavistadias);

    //adaptador 15dias

    ListView lista15dias = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu15dias);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listavista15dias = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu15Das);

    lista15dias.setAdapter(listavista15dias);

    //adaptador mes

    ListView listames = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.menumes);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listavistames =new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menumes);

    listames.setAdapter(listavistames);

    return view ;
}

}
```

**fragment_inicio.xml** (diseño el cual esta vinculado el InicioF.java)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.InicioF">



    <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:text="Proximos Dias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menudias"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:text="Proximos 15 Dias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu15dias"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:text="Proximo Mes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menumes"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**imagen explicativa**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si carga los datos pero no puedo verlo por q no se genera un scroll  de hecho, en "próximos 15 días" sale TARE, y en ese lugar minimante se genera un scroll pero para la lista mes no se ve

Comment: Por favor lee esto antes de escribir otra pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pon un ScrollView

Comment: disculpa pero, como hago eso?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view